# Swagger error: additionalProperty: 3XX, 4XX, 5XX

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have added added few error code in the swagger responses section:
201, 3XX, 400, 401, 4XX, 5XX.

Also, as per swagger2.0 doc you can have:
"The following range definitions are allowed: 1XX, 2XX, 3XX, 4XX, and 5XX. If a response range is defined using an explicit code, the explicit code definition takes precedence over the range definition for that code."

But still I get the error: 
"should NOT have additional properties. additionalProperty: 3XX, 4XX, 5XX"

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That quote is from the OpenAPI 3.0 Specification, not 2.0.

The [2.0 spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/2.0.md) does not support wildcard response codes. You need to use specific codes, such as `200`, `400`, `404`, etc., and you can use the `default` response to match all HTTP codes that are not covered individually by your spec.

Comment: Thanks Helen. That worked. It seems I was on 3.0 specification (and was using 2.0)